# Matlab Error : Cannot find an exact (case-sensitive) match

Tags: matlab

I was wondering if someone can help me to resolve a problem with a program in Matlab.

I'm not well experienced in Matlab,  and I'm supposed to do a projet for " Face Recognition by histogram" I just imported the code but when I want to run it I have this error :

Cannot find an exact (case-sensitive) match for 'STRCAT'

The closest match is: strcat
in C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2012a\toolbox\matlab\strfun\strcat.m

I work with the R2012a version .

Can anyone help me please.

Thank You.

Comment: Have you thought about accepting the good answer?

Answer (score 8):

The language is now case sensitive, having transitioned recently from being case insensitive. Use `strcat` rather than `STRCAT`.

I guess your code dates from the (bad) old days and needs to be updated to the new case sensitive orthodoxy.